# Displaying MKRoute on MKMapView in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview

I'm using MKDirectionsRequest to find a MKRoute between two points. 
The response will be displayed on the MKMapView using this code:

```
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
         }
         else
         {
             [_mapView removeOverlays:_mapView.overlays];
             for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
             {
                 [_mapView insertOverlay:route.polyline atIndex:0 level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
             }
         }
     }];
```

My question is, if there is a proper way to update the MKRoute if the user is moving. Atm I'm using

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation
```

to recognize movement and in this method I'm removing the MKRoute overlay and calculating and adding the new with the new user location.
I'm wondering if there is a way to compute the route only one time and updating the overlay programmatically?

**Edit:**
I found this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRouteStep_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKRouteStep in Apples Dev Docs.
I guess i have to do something like

```
for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
{
   for (MKRouteStep *step in route.steps) 
   {
      [_mapView insertOverlay:step.polyline atIndex:0 level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
   }
}
```

but how can i recognize which steps are *behind* the actual user location?

**Edit:** An other option could be to use a timer which triggers the event (removing the old overlay and adding the new one). What do you think?

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15 target:self selector:@selector(addRouteOverlay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: I don't recommend the timer because then you could be needlessly updating the route even if the user hasn't moved.  Simplest option is to do it in didUpdateUserLocation but only if the user has moved X meters since the last route was plotted.  Unrelated but if you add the plain "iOS" tag to the question it might get more attention (as well syntax-highlighting the code properly).

Comment: I have done some thing like this before, but not sure why you want to make a route map only when the user is moving. You can make the route with MKPolyLine on the map for the first time itself between the start & the end point. Later if the user moves, you can show user's updated location on map with the default Current Location Symbol (The blue color Small Circle). Please clarify so that I can suggest something,

Comment: The user location is displayed correctly. e.g. for a route from A->B->C the user location is at A and the route is displayed correctly but when the user moved to B the route is still displayed from A->C not from B->C.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but rather than using a timer, I'd use `MKMapViewDelegate` method `didUpdateUserLocation` and only update if the change from the last saved user location was significant. (Or you could use `CLLocationManager` and get notifications of user location change via that.)

Answer (score -2):

I have a nice solution to do this kind of work.

Simply, get destination location like below with lat (like -34.059811) and long (like 150.769238).

```
CLLocation  *destinationLocation=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-34.059811 longitude:150.769238];
```

and pass this lat long in below url string,you can directly pass this lat long in string,

```
NSString* strLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%f,%f",destinationLocation.latitude,destinationLocation.longitude];
```

Now make a url,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [strLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Open this url in browser or **UIWebView** and refresh that page with timer and see the magic,route will automatically update according to current location and destination location,you don't need to update current location every time.

Thanks.